# Altitude zoom google maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps V2 for Android, and I want to set Altitude in meters but the parameter in CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(...,...,zoom) when zoom is a float value between 2 and 21. Anybody knows the factor conversion for zoom to altitude in meters?

Comment: What do you think for this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750373/calculate-height-above-map-given-zoom-level-in-google-maps ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Zoom in meters or latitude/longitude in meters?

Comment: level Zoom in meters

Comment: You can't measure that. Different pictures are taken (by the satellite) for different locations.